# CKEditor Walker get selection only

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I'm trying to wrap the selection on pressing backspace. Now the key press part is already working but now i'm trying to wrap the selection within a span.. also when there are block elements within the selection. but i noticed that in CKEDITOR 4 the walker gets the full element instead of the selected part only.

The documentation on http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.walker says otherwise, it sais that it will break elements to show the block boundry's but why isn't it working then?

My code so far:

```
var walker = new CKEDITOR.dom.walker( editor.getSelection().getRanges()[0] ), node;
walker.evaluator = function(node){
    node = "<span name='wasSelected'>" + node.getText()+ "</span>";
    return true;
};
walker.checkBackward();
```

Note:
This was an attempt to answer a earlier question that i posted: [CKEditor Inline selection wrapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15568732/ckeditor-inline-selection-wrapping)

That question has a solution now, but still i would like to know why it doesn't do what the api sais. am i doing something wrong?

Comment: and i know that the line with node ="element"; won't work.. but i was refering to the fact that the evaluator node variable returns full nodes when only a part of the text of the node is selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm... I guess that documentation is wrong. I created a ticket and I will investigate that soon: https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/10261

Anyway, AFAIK walker **does not** call evaluator on fragments of included nodes. It call evaluator on every **entered** node. I haven't found anything that could change the DOM in its code.

Comment: I did know that, i was looking for text nodes ;)

Comment: If you knew that, then I don't understand your question :P

Comment: The question that i would like to have answered was the last one.. Like i wrote. The question has a solution already. But i still like to know why it wasn't doing what the doucmention said. And you're working on that issue i think. refering to your ticket?

Comment: It is just an outdated doc I guess. I'm not 100% sure, because I'm CKEditor core dev for around 1.5 year only, so I don't know the entire history of this class.

Comment: It would be nice if you guess can add this, because in my case it's exactly what i needed. But the applyStyle function did the job for now.. The only think is that you should expect that function under the selection element. not under the editor..but that's a comment a bit off-topic i guess

Comment: You can have selection outside editor or in non-editable places - applying style to those kinds of selections would be strange. Also, when applying style the editor configuration should be taken into consideration. Of course grouping all methods in editor object doesn't make sense too, but a correct object design very often is too much bloated.