# How to wrap selected text in ckeditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I wanted to wrap selected words in `CKEditor` in a `<p>` element.

From:

```
<p>This is a paragraph. And this is Selected text.</p>
```

To:

```
<p>This is a paragraph. And this is</p>
<p class="myclass">Selected text.</p>
```

I found some code:

```
( function() {
    CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'qna', { 
        init: function( editor ) {
            editor.addCommand( 'insertQnA', { 
                exec : function( editor ) {    
                    if(CKEDITOR.env.ie) {
                        editor.getSelection().unlock(true); 
                            var selected_text = editor.getSelection().getNative().createRange().text; 
                    } else { 
                        var selected_text = editor.getSelection().getNative();
                    }
                    editor.insertHtml('[before]' + selected_text + '[after]'); 
                } 
            }); 
            editor.ui.addButton( 'qna', { 
                label: 'Insert QnA', 
                command: 'insertQnA', 
                icon: this.path + 'images/qna.png'
            }); 
        } 
    });
})();
```

I wanted to replace the `[before]` and `[after]` with `<p class"myclass">` and `</p>` but it doesn't work.

I'm quite a newbie in JS/Jquery. I hope you can shed some light on it for me.

**EDIT: From Spon's reply.**

```
( function() {
  CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'qna', { 
    init: function( editor ) {
      editor.addCommand( 'insertQnA', { 
        exec : function( editor ) {    
          editor.applyStyle(new CKEDITOR.style({
            Element : 'p', 
            Attributes : { class : 'Myclass' }, 
            Styles : { color : '#ff0000','font-family' : 'Courier'} 
          }));
        } 
      }); 
      editor.ui.addButton( 'qna', { 
        label: 'Insert QnA', 
        command: 'insertQnA', 
        icon: this.path + 'images/question.png'
      }); 
    } 
  });
})();
```

The above code wraps the selected text/words in a `<span>` element for some unknown reason.

Example:

From...

```
<p>This is a paragraph. And this is Selected text.</p>
```

To...

```
<p>This is a paragraph. And this is <span>Selected text.</span></p>
```

This is not what I want.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
exec : function( editor ) {
  var selected_text = editor.getSelection().getSelectedText(); // Get Text
  var newElement = new CKEDITOR.dom.element("p");              // Make Paragraff
  newElement.setAttributes({style: 'myclass'})                 // Set Attributes
  newElement.setText(selected_text);                           // Set text to element
  editor.insertElement(newElement);                            // Add Element
}
```

This will fix it.. This is the Exec part as you can see.

Comment: @sopns This will not preserve your html formatting. How would you do it if you want to preserve html formatting.

Comment: @RohitKumar If you make a new question, i will anwser it for you. Tomorrow i'm on work. and can look it up for you, Because i already did it. But for this topic it is off-topic.

Comment: [This example](http://ckeditor.com/comment/56386#comment-56386) wraps a selection while preserving formatting in the selection. Just replace <b/> with <whatever tag>

Comment: I tried your code but it does not add any button ... I am using latest ckeditr

Comment: @umair, i'm not actively working with ckeditor anymore. But only the exec code won't add a button did you check that the way of adding an button did not change? Also that issue seems inrelated to this post and your best bet would be making an new question.

Comment: Hey, I know `But only the exec code won't add a button` ... anyways I have successfully added my button using tutorial from Ckeditor4 website ... they have a very nice tutorial ...thanks for reply though

Answer (score 4):

Duplicate see [Stackoverflow: Ckeditor Selection wrapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15568732/ckeditor-inline-selection-wrapping)

```
editor.applyStyle(new CKEDITOR.style({Element : 'p', Attributes : { class : 'Myclass' }, Styles : { color : '#ff0000','font-family' : 'Courier' } ));
```

This piece of code makes sure that if you have multiple block level selection, that you will keep the same structure. (If you make your p.myclass inline offcourse).

```
<p>This is a paragraph. And this is </p><p> Selected text.</p>
```

this example will be merged and output as:

```
<p>This is a paragraph. </p><p class="myClass">And this is  Selected text.</p>
```

But this example:

```
<div>This is a paragraph. And this is</div><div>  Selected text.</div>
```

this example will be merged and output as:

```
<div>This is a paragraph. <P class="myclass">And this is</p></div><div><P class="myclass">  Selected text.</p></div>
```

Comment: You mean in the plugin? You need to replace the code under exec:function(editor) { //My Code }, then it should work. or isn't that what you mean?

Comment: I updated the question above containing your code...It throws this error. `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'call' of undefined`

Comment: Update my anwser and your, i forgot this: new CKEDITOR.style();, Also look at this url.. it is from the old Ckeditor but there didn't change a lot http://dev.ckeditor.com/wiki/Components/Styles

Comment: Thanks spon...almost near.... using this code `editor.applyStyle(new CKEDITOR.style({Element : 'p', Attributes : { class : 'Myclass' }, Styles : { color : '#ff0000','font-family' : 'Courier' }}));` when I click the button it wraps my selected text to `span` element. Any idea?

Comment: ninjascorner, i'm sorry but i missed the fact that all block elements have a different flow. when you set element to an block or inline-block element it will change the container tags. Then i don't think this will work for you.. Is there a possibility that you use an inline element? i'll try to find you a solution like the soltion of wasif.. a moment.

Answer (score 4):

In case you want a universal solution that works both select text and any number of elements then this will work:

```
var selectedHtml = "";
var selection = editor.getSelection();
if (selection) {
    selectedHtml = getSelectionHtml(selection);
}
editor.insertHtml('something' + selectedHtml + 'something');
```

You will need two additional functions:

```
/**
    Get HTML of a range.
*/
function getRangeHtml(range) {
    var content = range.extractContents();
    // `content.$` is an actual DocumentFragment object (not a CKEDitor abstract)
    var children = content.$.childNodes;
    var html = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        var child = children[i];
        if (typeof child.outerHTML === 'string') {
            html += child.outerHTML;
        } else {
            html += child.textContent;
        }
    }
    return html;
}
/**
    Get HTML of a selection.
*/
function getSelectionHtml(selection) {
    var ranges = selection.getRanges();
    var html = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {
        html += getRangeHtml(ranges[i]);
    }
    return html;
}
```

Note that in CKEditor 4.5 you actually have `getHtml` function so `getRangeHtml` could be simplified by using `content.getHtml()`. See [documentFragment doc](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.documentFragment).

Answer (score 3):

Worth noting the CKEDITOR.style syntax has (apparently) changed in CKEditor 4; to use editor.applyStyle() (Which is preferable in some cases so you don't get a bunch of nested HTML), change the `editor.applyStyle()` stanza in the question's second example to:

```
editor.applyStyle(new CKEDITOR.style({
        element : 'p', 
        attributes : { class : 'Myclass' }, 
        styles : { color : '#ff0000','font-family' : 'Courier'} 
      })
);
```

Notice how the keys are all lowercase now.

It would really help if they'd [document](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.style) this -- the only documentation there at the moment says "TODO..."!

Comment: Thanks a ton! This should probably be the accepted answer...

Answer (score 1):

It is working for both image and text in ckeditor

```
var selection = CKEDITOR.instances['content'].getSelection();
if (selection.getType() == CKEDITOR.SELECTION_ELEMENT) {
  var selectedContent = selection.getSelectedElement().$.outerHTML;
} else if (selection.getType() == CKEDITOR.SELECTION_TEXT) {
  if (CKEDITOR.env.ie) {
    selection.unlock(true);
    selectedContent = selection.getNative().createRange().text;
  } else {
    selectedContent = selection.getNative();
    console.log("The selectedContent is: " + selectedContent);
  }
}
```

here content is textarea id

Answer (score 0):

This code example add plugin with button for CK editor which wraps html with class 'vip-content'.
This handle each type of elements: clicked inside text, clicked on element (e.g. img) or selected some elements (some lines of code).

```
(function () {
const WRAP_CONTENT_CLASS = 'vip-content';

function getSelectionHtml(selection) {
    var ranges = selection.getRanges();
    var html = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {
        html += ranges[i].extractContents().getHtml();
    }

    return html;
}

CKEDITOR.plugins.add('wrapcontent', {
    init: function (editor) {
        editor.addCommand('WrapContent', {
            exec: function () {
                var selection = editor.getSelection();
                var div = new CKEDITOR.dom.element('div').addClass(WRAP_CONTENT_CLASS);

                // Process element
                if (selection.getSelectedElement()) {
                    div.append(selection.getSelectedElement());
                    editor.insertElement(div);

                    return;
                }

                if (selection.getNative().type === 'Caret') {
                    editor.applyStyle(new CKEDITOR.style({
                        element: 'div',
                        attributes: {class: WRAP_CONTENT_CLASS},
                    }));
                } else {
                    var html = getSelectionHtml(selection);
                    if (html !== '') {
                        div.setHtml(html);
                        editor.insertElement(div);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        editor.ui.addButton('WrapContent', {
            label: 'Wrap content',
            toolbar: 'insert',
            command: 'WrapContent',
            icon: this.path + 'icons/icon.png'
        });
    }
});
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this way that is better to get add-remove efecto for style:

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('my_style', {
    
    init: function (editor) {
        'use strict';
        editor.addCommand('my_style', {
            exec: function (editor) {
                var myStyle = new CKEDITOR.style({
                    element: 'span',
                    attributes: {class: 'my_style'}
                });

                if (myStyle.checkActive(editor.elementPath(), editor)) {
                    editor.removeStyle(myStyle);
                } else {
                    editor.applyStyle(myStyle);
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```